# Click a link in an image in MVC

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Orginally I have links for view in MVC 2.

```
      <div id="sidebar">
              <li> <%=Html.ActionLink("View1", "View1", "Home") %></li> 
              <li> <%=Html.ActionLink("View2", "View2", "Home") %></li>
              <li> <%=Html.ActionLink("View3", "View3", "Home") %></li>
      </div>
```

There is ImageMap control in web form, in which you can click different link to different page. Now I am going to replace the list in MVC with an image. By clicking different spots then we can go to different view. I just wonder whether there is a similar ImageMap in MVC?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a built-in solution for MVC.

But you could check this out: http://forums.asp.net/t/1644834.aspx/1?How+to+create+img+map+area+in+MVC+2

Comment: To be more clear, the ASP.NET ImageMap control is just a shim around the standard HTML concept of an image map.  Because MVC is much closer to the bare metal, they don't implement a special control for this, but the HTML approach will work just fine.